# Better coin toss with a draw?

Tags: c#, math, probability

I'm building a coin toss game for my chat bot, and I thought it would be fun to include a very rare occurrence of the coin landing on it's side. Based on this article, the odds are roughly 1 in 6000 for an American nickel:

> Extrapolations based on the model suggest that the probability of an American nickel landing on edge is approximately 1 in 6000 tosses.

I've created a solution that will work, but is heavy to one side or the other, in my last run it was heavy on a heads result (first 10 results across 3 iterations from zero to draw: 11 tails, 19 heads):

```
Tails. Tails. Heads. Heads. Tails. Tails. Heads. Heads. Heads. - Toss 11666 was a draw.
Heads. Tails. Tails. Heads. Heads. Tails. Tails. Tails. Heads. - Toss 6135 was a draw.
Heads. Tails. Heads. Heads. Heads. Tails. Heads. Heads. Heads. - Toss 24100 was a draw.
```

The code for this is very simple, though it allows the draw to *seemingly* occur less frequently than *approximately 1 in 6,000 iterations* due to the use of modulus on a random number between `5800` and `6200`:

```
int result = _random.Next(2);
if (++_tossCount % _random.Next(5800, 6200) == 0) {
    result = 2;
    _tossCount = 0;
}

switch (result) {
    case 0: return "Heads.";
    case 1: return "Tails.";
    default: return "It was a draw!";
}
```

`_random` and `_tossCount` are fields in the class initialized to `new Random()` and `0` respectively within the constructor (*they **can*** be initialized at the beginning of main, but ***outside of the iterator*** for replication purposes in a console application). The code above is a method returning a `string` that can be called within an iterator of your choosing to replicate the process. I used a `do-while` for testing, but a `for` would work all the same.

---

How can I improve the probability for equally distributing the results between heads and tails, along with landing a draw approximately every 6000 calls?

Comment: I don't understand where the numbers 5800 and 6200 come from.

Comment: @RobertHarvey they were random numbers chosen by me to add some randomness to the odds of getting a draw. Essentially to prevent the draw from occurring exactly every 6000 iterations.

Comment: Can't you choose a random number between, say, 0 and 6000. Numbers 0 - 2999 are heads, 3000 - 5999 are tails, 6000 is edge (all inclusive). Alternatively start by picking a number between 1 and 6000: if it's 6000 then you get edge. Otherwise, pick a number between 0 and 1 for heads vs tails.

Comment: @canton7 if you write up an answer with that for future readers, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: (Will do, once I'm out of meetings)

Comment: To get the odds exactly right, it would need to be 1 - 5999 heads, 6000 -11998 tails and 11999 - 12000 draw.

Comment: @oleksii it's a game where the toss count can be shared across thousands of users in production so really anyone could get a draw on their first flip. I just wanted to iron out the details in a smaller sample first. :)

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I figured 1/6001 was as close to 1/6000 as made no difference...

Comment: @canton7 Yes, it makes little difference, but might as well be exact :)

Comment: I don't think the rough estimate of 1/6000 is that accurate to start with :)

Comment: @canton7 good point lol but meh, rare enough for what I'm creating though haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the odds correct, you could create a random number between 1 and 12000, where the various results are represented by ranges:

```
enum CoinTossResult { Heads, Tails, Draw };
CoinTossResult TossCoin()
{
    return _random.Next(1, 12000) switch
    {
        <= 5999 => CoinToss.Heads,
        <= 11998 => CoinToss.Tails,
        _ => CoinToss.Draw
    };
}
```

The probability of a draw is now 1 in 6000. Heads and tails share the remaining 5999 in 6000 equally.

---

<sub>***NOTE**: The utilized syntax is only available in [C# 8 and higher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression).*</sub>

Comment: For the sake of future readers, would you mind including the .NET version required to use the switch expression syntax? I know it's in C# 8, but other readers may not and end up with a compiler error because of it. :)

Comment: @Tacoタコス Ok, I've added that.